# while passing object having the data above 100kb in client side does not able to call the service method using WCF services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

below method lstImprtlogisticare is the object having data above 100kb. If the object having below 100kb data it is working fine.If more than 100kb  getting communication exception as

```
The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
```

an the code is

```
public int ImportLogistiCareData(List<Importlogisticare> lstImportlogisticare, int VendorId, TransportationVendorTypes vendorType)
        {
            try
            {
                using (LINAServiceClient oLINAServiceClient = new LINAServiceClient())
                {
                    Mapper.CreateMap<Importlogisticare, IMPORTLOGISTICARE>()
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ID))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.REGION, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Region))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.TRIPID, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Trip_Id))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.JOBNO, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Job_No))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.DATEOFSERVICE, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Dateof_Service))                      
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.DATEOF_BIRTH, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Dateof_Birth))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.AGE, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Age))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.HOME_PHONE, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Home_Phone));
                    IMPORTLOGISTICARE[] oIMPORTLOGISTICARE = Mapper.Map<IMPORTLOGISTICARE[]>(lstImportlogisticare);

                    return oLINAServiceClient.ImportFile(null, oIMPORTLOGISTICARE, VendorId, Convert.ToInt32(lstImportlogisticare[0].LASTUPDATEDBY), vendorType);

                }
            }           
            catch (System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please improve your question's formatting.

Comment: You should avoid putting client proxies in using blocks. Use  the close method

Comment: @InvernoMuto using close() method will solve the problem?

Comment: if not solve, probably make possible understand the problem